# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.android.MultiDexLoader

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-multidex

Can anyone help me solving this error!
It's a Xamarin PCL project, and I'm just trying to add `Azure Notification Hub` to the **Android** project (it also have some dependencies to the Google `FireBase` libraries)

I've been trying Enabling and Disabling the **MultiDex** option in the project properties, but neither worked for me! (Actually, it just gives me another error message (**java.exe exited with code 2**)

```
[zygote] Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
[zygote] Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
[MultiDex] VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
[MultiDex] install
[MultiDex] VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: com.company.projectName, PID: 10919
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.android.MultiDexLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.MultiDexLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6242)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.MultiDexLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.company.projectname-N4Tg7Iqr9nh9NV79ZcKDyA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
[AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6227)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understood corrrectly: This is a Xamarin.Forms Solution and the Android Project is failing to build when you added the Azure Notification Hub which has a dependency on the Google Firebase?

Comment: @pinedax Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same error and was able to get things working by disabling Fast Assembly Deployment from the Android Build configuration.
[image]

This, however, only seems to work on the Build configuration, running on Release (with Fast Assembly disabled) results in the same error again :/